# sketch drawing tool - software design diagrams (uml)

Tags: drawing, uml, diagram

I've seen a few times people present software design diagrams in a kinda hand-writing sketching draft style. Is there any tool out there does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I like http://yuml.me. Also check out this list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools

Comment: Thanks, I like the scruffy look from yuml, that's exactly what I was looking for. But so far it only supports class,activity,use case diagrams, too limited at this stage.

Comment: 9 years later Yuml has changed nothing while we are at uml 2.5 now. That’s why I hate subscription services, no innovation and development

Answer (score 0):

Try "balsamiq" ... I think it's http://www.balsamiq.com/

Comment: Is it that difficult to type and check URL? I guess that's why someone downvoted.